# Custom message for those who don't have access

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom, sql, sql-server-2012, bi

How can I provide a custom message to a user who doesn't have access to a folder in  Microsoft Online SharePoint?

Appreciation in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no feature in SharePoint Online for custom Access denied page or message.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/240993.aspx

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/158042.aspx

There are couple of features available for company branding that is only available when you enable Azure Active Directory Premium.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532270.aspx